# Converting a Date in Text to a Date Field in Excel, i.e. 6/2/2017 9:24 AM EDT

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2007

I'm not new to Excel and or Access, but have never come across this before. A report was sent to me where a date field is being stored as text, but is outputted as 6/2/2017 9:24 AM EDT. I'm trying to convert this column into a date field so that I can do calculations off of it in Access. I wold love to do this in Access, but I think it might be easier to do in Excel. I've tried doing a text to column and then formatting the Cell as Date, i.e. 3/14/2001, but to no avail. I thought about doing a Left, but the date could be 6/2/2017 or 12/2/2017. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please take a moment to review the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour , 
How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , and more specifically, 
*How to Ask Good Questions* https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 
- you'll get better feedback and helpful answers if you put some thought in to your problem before coming to SO for help, and by including a specific problem with code *that you've tried* showing effort to solve the problem yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
=--LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-3)
```

Then format the cell as you wish.

[image]

Note, this only works if your local date format is `d/m/y` not `m/d/y` if that is the case you will need to parse the data bit by bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use substitue. Like this:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1;"EDT";"")
```

Comment: 1. not REPLACE, should be SUBSTITUTE. 2 you still need to make it a number as SUBSTITUTE will return a text string.  So either wrap it in `VALUE()` or `DATEVALUE` or multiply it by `--`.  This will turn the text into an actual date.  But good idea.

Comment: Good point. My excel is actually in portuguese and I mistranslated the function. The correct one is SUBSTITUE. If you set the field with the formula to be a date field you may not need to convert the date value to number to make comparisons, but he should keep in mind that maybe it will be required.

Comment: Even if you set it to date/time, it will not automatically convert as Excel does not convert a string returned by a formula automatically.  You can have the cell as a date time and type `blah` in it and `blah` will stay.  Same thing.  Excel will see it as text and it will not convert to a true date.  It will look like a date but when doing lookups it will fail as Excel will look for a number when comparing to a true date.

Comment: Yes it does not convert the value, but excel is able to compare the value returned from the formula (even if it's text) with another actual date value. I did some tests here and it went fine.
The question don't really have much details on the calculations that will be done, but that may be enough.

Comment: No it does not: http://imgur.com/a/7QeMm C1 is a true date, as in it is a number that is formatted in date/time.  B1 is the text return from `=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-3)`.  The VLOOKUP does not see them as a match.

Answer (score 0):

If you are saving it as a CSV or doing any copy/paste and want to make sure Excel doesn't convert it into a date type at reimport, you can add an apostrophe before the value which tells Excel to explicitly ignore what follows it. Here is one way to do it automatically using a macro.

Format the column/rows as text and add this to the workbook macros:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    With Target
        If IsDate(.Value) Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            .Value = "'" & .Value
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```